# Distance dependent Chinese Restaurant Process maybe

Tags: audio, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I'm new to machine learning and want to implement the distance dependent Chinese Restaurant process in MATLAB for the clustering of audio tracks.

I'm looking to use the dd-CRP on 26 features. I'm guessing the process might go like this

- Read in 1st feature vector and assign it a "table"
- Read in 2nd feature vector and compare it to the 1st "table", maybe using the cosine angle(due to high dimension) of the two vectors and if it agrees within some defined theta, join that table, else start a new one.
- Read in next feature and repeat step 2 for the new feature vector for each existing table.
- While this is occurring, I will be keeping track of how many tables there are.

I will be running the algorithm over say for example 16 audio tracks. The way the audio will be fed into the algorithm is the first feature vector will be from say the first frame from audio track 1, the second feature vector from form the first frame in track 2 etc. as I'm trying to find out which audio tracks like to cluster together most, but I don't want to define how many centroids there are. Obviously I'll have to keep track of which audio track is at which "table".

Does this make sense?

Comment: We like to handle specific issues with code. I see you haven't posted any. Try adding some to get some responses from us.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't written any code for the dd-CRP yet. I'm just looking to find out if the theory and my understanding of the problem is correct. I have plenty of code written for dealing with the audio and clustering it using k-means that works, but I'm looking expand on it.

Comment: It may not be relevant for matlab. Kindly remove the matlab tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Chinese Restaurant Process. This is a heuristic algorithm which has some similarity to a Chinese Restaurant Process. In a CRP everything is phrased in terms of priors over the assignments of items to clusters (the tables analogy), and these are combined with a likelihood function for each cluster (which formalises the similarity function you described). Inference is then done by Gibbs Sampling, which means non-deterministically sampling which cluster each track is assigned to in turn given all the other assignments. Variational methods for non-parametrics are still in a very preliminary state.

Why do you want to use a CRP? Do you think you'll get something out of it beyond more conventional clustering methods? The bar to entry for the implementation and proper understanding of non-parametrics is pretty high, and they're often of little practical use at the moment because of the constraints on inference I mentioned.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for getting back to me. The reason I was looking at the CRP is due to the infinite amount of clusters. What I'm actually trying to do is cluster audio tracks from multi-track recordings. Traditionally in audio production you would group these audio tracks based on there content i.e. group drums with other drums, guitars with other guitars. I'm extracting low level features from each of the audio tracks and cluster them based on there features instead of following traditional sound engineering practice, which is generally just a rule of thumb.

Comment: Would I possibly be better off looking at time series clustering in this case?

Comment: I think general clustering is fine, and there are clustering methods which do not require a priori specification of the number of clusters (although CRPs are infinite models, there will always be a finite number of clusters for a finite number of data points). Take a look at DBSCAN for instance, which is popular enough that you shouldn't struggle to find an implementation.

Comment: I agree there will be a finite amount of clusters, but I want the data define how many clusters there should. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `X-means` algorithm, which automatically determines the optimal number of centroids (and hence number of clusters) based on the Bayesian Information Criterion (or BIC). In short, the algorithm looks for how dense each cluster is, and how far is each cluster from the other.